# find all files/directories belonging to a specified module

Tags: module, code

Is there a standard method or has anyone found a way to somehow parse the directories of a magento install with a script of some sort to find all files and directories belonging to a module?

I'm hoping to be in a position where I can choose to both read and copy all occurrences of a module or just delete it as the script finds files and directories belonging to it.

This part of my requirement would be easy to implement myself if there was already something available to scan the magento install for a given module.

Example of process

```
select module - 'example module name'

select action - 'delete module' or 'copy module to chosen location'

run(); /* search module for all files belonging to selected module and execute chosen action */
```

I'm expecting to have to write the final part of this myself but if anyone has a starting point for me it would be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [MEFF – Magento Extension File Finder](https://github.com/tegansnyder/meff).

> The purpose of this utility is to list all the files responsible for a
>   Magento extension and their locations.